# How insert the data with DateTime type into SQL Server database using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, sql-server-2008-r2

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I am facing a problem with inserting some data to the database. I have a form for creating Event. The filled data should be inserted to the database. I have the following database design:

Columns: `ID, Title, Description, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, IsActive`
(*`StartDateTime` and `EndDateTime` are `DateTime` data types*)

When I tried to insert data, I faced the following problem and I don't know why:

[image]

My code-behind (C#):

```
protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=RegistrationSysDB;Integrated Security=True;";
        string insertCommand = "INSERT INTO Events (Title, Description, Location, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) values (@Title, @Description, @Location, @StartDateTime, @EndDateTime)";

        string title = txtTitle.Text;
        string description = txtDescription.Text;
        string location = txtLocation.Text;
        string startDateTime = start_DateTime.ToString();
        string endDateTime = end_DateTime.ToString();

        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            //open DB Connection
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertCommand, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", title);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", description);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", location);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDateTime", startDateTime);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDateTime", endDateTime);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            conn.Close();
        }

        MultiView1.SetActiveView(ViewConfirm);
    }
```

My ASP.NET code:

```
<div id="contactform">
                <fieldset>
                        <label for="title">
                            Title</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" CssClass="text-input" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter a subject for your message"
                            ControlToValidate="txtTitle"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                        <label for="description">
                            Description</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="textarea" Rows="6" cols="50"
                            runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter your message"
                            ControlToValidate="txtDescription"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                        <label for="location">
                            Location</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocation" CssClass="text-input" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter your message"
                            ControlToValidate="txtLocation"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                        <label for="start_DateTime">
                            Start Date & Time</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="start_DateTime" CssClass="textarea" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <%--<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="start_DateTime" 
                                                        PopupPosition="Right">
                        </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>--%>
                        <br />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter your message"
                            ControlToValidate="start_DateTime"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                        <label for="end_DateTime">
                            End Date & Time</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="end_DateTime" CssClass="textarea" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <%--<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="end_DateTime" 
                                                        Format=" PopupPosition="Right">
                        </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>--%>
                        <br />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter your message"
                            ControlToValidate="end_DateTime"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                        <asp:Button ID="submitButton"  runat="server" CssClass="button" 
                            Text="Create &rarr;" onclick="submitButton_Click" />
              </fieldset>
            </div>
```

FYI, I am using jQuery UI `DateTimePicker` for inserting the `StartDateTime` and `EndDateTime`.

So how can I insert the data with `DateTime` type into the database?

**UPDATE #1:**

I changed my code to the following:

```
protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=RegistrationSysDB;Integrated Security=True;";
        string insertCommand = "INSERT INTO Events (Title, Description, Location, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) values (@Title, @Description, @Location, @StartDateTime, @EndDateTime)";

        string title = txtTitle.Text;
        string description = txtDescription.Text;
        string location = txtLocation.Text;
        string startDateTime = start_DateTime.ToString();
        string endDateTime = end_DateTime.ToString();

        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            //open DB Connection
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertCommand, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", title);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", description);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", location);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDateTime", "'" + startDateTime + "'");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDateTime", "'" + endDateTime + "'");
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            conn.Close();
        }

        MultiView1.SetActiveView(ViewConfirm);
    }
```

and I got the following error:

[image]

Comment: maybe this work : cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDateTime", "'"+startDateTime+"'");

Comment: I tried it and I got another error. Could you please have a look at my updated code?

Comment: The second error is that you have two `StartDateTime`. Change the second one to `EndDateTime`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling ToString on the textbox instead of retrieving the text from it.  So the value that is getting passed to the database is the string `"System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox"` instead of the actual date/time.

Try replacing this:

```
string startDateTime = start_DateTime.ToString();
string endDateTime = end_DateTime.ToString();
```

With this:

```
string startDateTime = start_DateTime.Text;
string endDateTime = end_DateTime.Text;
```

The first code-behind you had (before the update) should work with this change... at least it did for me. :)

Answer (score 2):

Both lines say @StartDateTime. Change the second one to @EndDateTime :)

```
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDateTime", "'" + startDateTime + "'");
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDateTime", "'" + endDateTime + "'");
```

And you don't have to convert them to strings nor add the `'`